# GTK with C and Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, gtk

I have decided to use the **GTK** library and I have been messing around with it.

My problem does not lie within C or GTK itself, it all about **Eclipse**. Even though my applications compile and run with no errors, but Eclipse is constantly telling me that there are problems such as:

> GTK_DIALOG_MODAL, GTK_MESSAGE_INFO, GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE... could not be resolved.

Is there a way to make Eclipse understand what is going on?

Comment: This question should probably be moved to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess Eclipse cannot find GTK's header files.  You can tell it where to look for them by adding one or more include directories to the project properties:

```
Project → Properties → C/C++ General → Paths and Symbols → Includes
```

This works for Eclipse Indigo and Juno, at least.